# Can I build the Open Source Routing Machine for Offline Use?

Tags: c++, openstreetmap, osrm

I'm planning to create a trajectory generator for an autonomous vehicle, and I want to extract the trajectory from OSRM. I've already exported the OSM map I want to work on (about ~300h and has well defined roads) and I've also prepared the OSRM back-end in my Linux.

Is there a way that I can have an interface (offline) and extract the trajectory (lines and angles) that the routing machine outputs?

Any assistance on this question will do. Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems like the sort of problem better suited to a discussion in the OSRM IRC channel, no?

Comment: If I may ask, how does OSRM IRC channel work? What do I do after logging in?

Comment: Teaching you how to use IRC is off-topic here! Did you use Google? There are many, many, many, many guides on using IRC on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can build OSRM backend in your own machine, see instructions [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-OSRM).

When you calculate a route between two points (viaroute service), the server response by default sets to true the parameter geometry, where you have the trajectory of the route. If you want to know how to parse the JSON answer and  the geometry, have a look as an example to the implementation of the [frontend of OSRM](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-frontend-v2). Take also into account that the geometry of the route is returned by default compressed (geometry is a list of [lat, lng] pairs).

Cheers!